# How to add view in a linear layout dynamically

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater

I have called a make layout method that takes input label and input

```
public void makeLayout(String label, String inputType) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), label + " " + inputType,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    // fill in any details dynamically here
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText("your text");

    // insert into main view
    ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.AdvancedCatalogContainer);
    insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}
```

now on the basis of input type argument, i want to add view in the layout activity main ( inside any linear layout ).
I called this method multiple times but want to display all view at once that is when the whole layout is dynamically created. What approach should be there? I want to add one thing that makes layout method of main activity is called from an asynchronous task. 
I need your valuable suggestion as I am new to android technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to get familiar with java (in my opinion).

1) declare a linear layout at XML layout. like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/AdvancedCatalogContainer"
       >
        </LinearLayout>
```

2) Get a referance to that view:

```
private LinearLayout rootView=findViewById(R.id.AdvancedCatalogContainer);
```

3) Declare a method like this:

```
public void fillLayout(LinearLayout root,TextView  v){
  v.setText("your text")
  root.addView(v);
}
```

4) Call this method in your onCreate method or anywhere in ui thread.

```
... extends AsycTask<blah,blah,blah>{
onPostExecute(blah){

  for(many times){

    fillLayout(linearLayout,textView);

  }

}
```

**Edit**

If you want to show a collection of data like a scrolling list please consider using [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) or [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead.

Comment: one more doubt will it refresh layout every time i add a view. How to add all view in root layout in one refresh. I hope you get what i mean to say.

Comment: no it it will add a new line to your linear layout . You can call root.removeAllViews(); to refresh your view