# Dynamic views not displaying in fragment: android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I have a ScrollView with a child LinearLayout. I am programmatically adding TextViews and NumberPickers to the LinearLayout through a separate View method. However the dynamic objects do not display when the tab containing the ScrollView is clicked.

Here is my code:

```js
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_tab, container, false);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

  rootview.findViewById(R.id.scroll_config);
  viewFunds();
  return rootview;
}
```

Here is the separate method I have mentioned that dynamically adds objects to the LinearLayout:

```js
public View viewFunds(View rootview) {

  ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
  scrollView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_config);
  LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
  linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.ll_config);
  //final View linearLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ll_config);
  linearLayout.removeAllViews(); //clear layout first - LINE WITH ISSUE
  linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  //create dynamic objects inside scrollview and dynamic linear layout - horizontal
  for (int i = 0; i < res2.getCount(); i++) {
    LinearLayout llh = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    llh.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_llh = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llh.setLayoutParams(lp_llh);

    linearLayout.addView(llh);

    NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_np = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    numberPicker.setLayoutParams(lp_np);
    numberPicker.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //showMessage("value",res2.getString(3));
    numberPicker.setValue(Integer.parseInt(res2.getString(2))); //
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText( /*textArray[i] + " " +*/ res2.getString(1));


    llh.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(numberPicker);

  }
  return scrollView;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you doing totally wrong check this sample how to add views runtime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31047502/how-to-add-view-in-a-linear-layout-dynamically

Comment: This is in the context of using a Fragment with dynamic views. The example you mentioned is not related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using fragment u have to find view with reference of fragment root view also your below statement doing nothing i will advise u to go through android basic components

```
 rootview.findViewById(R.id.scroll_config);
```

to solve problem do following

```
public View viewFunds(View rootview) {

  ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.scroll_config);//considering scroll_config is scroll view in xml
  LinearLayout linearLayout =(LinearLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.ll_config);//considering ll_config is LinearLayout  in xml

  linearLayout.removeAllViews(); //clear layout first - LINE WITH ISSUE
  linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  //create dynamic objects inside scrollview and dynamic linear layout - horizontal
  for (int i = 0; i < res2.getCount(); i++) {
    LinearLayout llh = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    llh.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_llh = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llh.setLayoutParams(lp_llh);

    linearLayout.addView(llh);

    NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_np = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    numberPicker.setLayoutParams(lp_np);
    numberPicker.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //showMessage("value",res2.getString(3));
    numberPicker.setValue(Integer.parseInt(res2.getString(2))); //
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText( /*textArray[i] + " " +*/ res2.getString(1));


    llh.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(numberPicker);///chek in which layou you want to add numberPicker

  }
}
```

and in oncreateview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_tab, container, false);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

  viewFunds(rootview);
  return rootview;
}
```

also go through android training https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Sorry I should not have included the line `rootview.findViewById(R.id.scroll_config);` , I was trying out things earlier. I already updated the code based on your above suggestion but the dynamic views on the linearLayout are still not displayed. I updated the VewFunds method above to include the return line which I forgot to include earlier.Kindly check the updated code above. Thanks

Comment: Yes it worked. The objects now are displayed. Thanks much! I just forgot to update these lines based on your code: `ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.scroll_config);` and `LinearLayout linearLayout =(LinearLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.ll_config);`